# javascript: grab last string after white space

Tags: javascript

If I have a string that could have any amount of items in it seperated by a space, ie: "ab abc" or "ab abc abcd", how do I set a variable to always grab the last piece (abc in the first case, and abcd in the second case)?

Comment: And when there is no space?

Answer (score 3):

Split the array by whitespace. Grab the last element in the array.

eg.

```
s = "the fox went and did something";
arr = s.split(" ");
console.log(arr[arr.length-1]);
```

Comment: If you don't care for the array, a one-line `s.split(" ").pop()` will suffice, too.

Comment: @IngoBürk - even better!

Comment: Well if you are talking about speed, pop() is slower in chrome/ie than actually referencing the last index like you are doing.

Comment: If this needs to be so efficient for this to matter at all, you have bigger problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a simple function like this:

```
function getLastWord(string) {
  var newString = string.split(" ");
  return newString[newString.length - 1];
}
```

and the call it with:

```
var word = getLastWord("My name is Simone"); /* Will result "Simone" */
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var str = "ab abc abcd", _str = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1)
```

See [String.prototype.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) , [String.prototype.lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

```js
var str = "ab abc abcd", _str = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1); 
document.write(_str)
```

Answer (score -1):

Basic regular expression

```
"asdf asdfffffff".match(/\s([^\s]+)$/)[1]
```

- `\s` Matches whitespace
- `([^\s]+)`  Matches series of characters that are not a whitespace
- `$`  Matches end of line

Comment: Why in the world would you use a regular expression for such a simple task? Even more so considering that the OP is obviously on a beginner level (edit: sorry, the -1 was an accident -- undid it)

Comment: And re-added the -1 for rudeness and flagged it. Cheerio.

Comment: Regarding your edit: Yes, it is a valid answer, technically. I don't see how this justifies being rude for asking *why* you would approach a simple question with such heavy instruments. And over-engineered solutions are in fact a good reason for discussion and/or downvoting. But that's not what mine is for.